# Galaxy A3 2016 bluetooth problem.Devices are visible but won't pair

Tags: samsung, bluetooth

I have a Samsung Galaxy A3 2016 Android Version 7.0 .

Pairing with other devices was working just fine until the last couple of months .

Lately my device can discover other devices , but pairing is not working with any device .

I tried to pair it with my laptop, beats and a LED bulb but it's not working .

Any ideas ?

Answer (score -1):

It may not work but I just rebooted the phone then paired again and it worked !  Mike